# DefaultParameterValue Attribute throws Error in Visual Studio 2015 while working fine in 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a following piece of code:

```
  [DefaultParameterValue(false)]
  public bool IsDataAvailable{ get; set; }
```

This used to work fine when I was using **Visual Studio 2013** Professional.
Recently, I upgraded to **Visual Studio 2015** Professional version and this line started giving Error:

> "CS0592   Attribute 'DefaultParameterValue' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'parameter' declarations."

I could not get any help from google why this behavior occurs. Any idea?

Comment: This the intended behavior. You can use the `DefaultParameterValueAttribute` only on a parameter. Maybe there was a bugfix in the C# compiler and now it (correctly) complains about the invalid usage.

Comment: Do you have any specific link or reference about this change or bugfix in C# compiler? Though I know something has changed,  I want to gain more knowledge about it to know how to replace that code with alternate one.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 uses a new open source Roslyn compiler that has been created anew from scratch (and written in C#). Visual Studio 2013 uses an "old" native compiler. So I just **suppose** that there was a bug in the old compiler and Microsoft fixed it in Roslyn. Maybe you can ask Microsoft directly. But the current behavior (a CS0592 error) is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was a Bug in VS2013 and they fixed it in VS2015. That could be a 
 reason why it workd in VS2013.

You cant use DefaultParameterValue on Properties cause its for "Parameter".
 You can use it for Methods.

If you want a default value for your Setter you can do somehting like this:

```
    private bool _IsDataAvailable =false;
    public bool GetIsDataAvailable()
    {
        return _IsDataAvailable;
    }
    public void SetIsDataAvailable([DefaultParameterValue(false)] bool b)
    {
        _IsDataAvailable = b;
    }
```

Greetings

Comment: Is there any way to set "DefaultParameterValue" without changing the property to functions?

Comment: What are you looking for? Do you want a default value in your  Property when u dont set it?

Comment: Yes, the existing code does that but its not compiling in Studio 2015.

Comment: public bool MyBool{get;set;}=false;

This give the property a default value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am aware of this way but cannot use this as we are constrained to use .NET Framework 4.0.(To make sure more people with old systems can use our product) Is there any other way?

Comment: hm I dont know
 maybe something like this:

private Bool_MyBool
public Bool MyBool{
  get { return _MyBool; } 
  set { _MyBool= value ?? false; }
}